# How to create a string containing a double-apostrophe?

Tags: string, escaping

This line of code:

```
String s = " " ";
```

does not seem to work.

I want to create a single character string containing a double-apostrophe. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Mentioning what programming language you are using might be a good idea.

Comment: [Escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

Comment: Please could you tag the language?

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
String s = "\"";
```

Comment: Normally escape strings are accepted in majority of languages!

Answer (score 0):

Escape characters are used to signal an alternative interpretation of a series of characters.

For example, if you wanted String to have the value:

> The question is, "to be or not to be"

You would need to use an escape character to keep the compiler from interpreting the " character as the end of the string:

```
 String A = "The question is \"to be or not to be\""
```

Implementations:

**VB**

`"" or Chr(34)`

**C / C++**

`\"`

**Java / PHP**

`\"`

**Unicode**

`\u0022`

**Python**

`\"`

**XML**

`&quot;`